# Generate CEF log files with logback

Tags: logback

I'd like to be able to generate Common Event Format (CEF) log files using logback. Does anyone know of any projects or resources out there which can do this, or do I have to write a custom logback Layout? I apologize in advance if this isn't the right forum to put this question in.